# Using pycountry to check for name/common_name/official_name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where the column 'Country' contains names of countries that I'm trying to convert to the alpha_3 country code (in a new column labelled 'Code'). I'm using pycountry for this, but am running into errors as some of the country names fall under the pycountry 'name', while others are pycountry 'common_name' and 'official_name'.

How can I check all three when converting my list of countries?  For reference, I am currently using the following function to get the codes (right now it's only looking at 'name'):

```
def get_country_code(x):
    return pycountry.countries.get(name=x).alpha_3

df = get_data('data.csv')
df['Code'] = df['Country'].apply(get_country_code)
```

Edit: Sample data:

```
Country
Afghanistan
Bolivia
Iran (Islamic Republic of)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you add some data sample, 3-4 rows?

Comment: Can you try all the attributes and catch the exceptions?

Comment: @jezrael just added!

Comment: @Eric What do you mean? I'm currently trying the lookup function (just discovered it), which I guess tries all the attributes, but it's still not full proof. I'm having to see where the file stops running, check which value the error is pointing to one at a time, and write code to rename the value.

Answer (score 4):

Use `pycountry.countries.lookup`

```
>>> pycountry.countries.lookup('Bolivia')
Country(alpha_2='BO', alpha_3='BOL', common_name='Bolivia', name='Bolivia, Plurinational State of', numeric='068', official_name='Plurinational State of Bolivia')
```

Comment: This won't work for 'Iran', as it only recognizes 'Iran, Islamic Republic of'. I am aware that I could use regex to make this work, but I'm not sure how to.

Comment: Well then, you'd have to create your own mapping from names to codes. Shouldn't be that bad, there's only 200 or so of them.

Answer (score 1):

This, albeit not being elegant at all, worked for me:

```
def country_code_converter(input_countries):
    """
    :param input_countries: list containing the name of the countries (can be numpy array)
    :return: list with the ISO alpha 3 codes for the given input ('Unknown Country' if no match found)
    """
    countries = {}
    countries_official = {}
    countries_common = {}

    #loops over all of the countries contained in the pycountry library and populates dictionary
    for country in pycountry.countries:
        countries[country.name] = country.alpha_3

    #loops over the alpha_3 codes from the countries dictionary
    #populates dictionary containing official names and codes
    for alpha_3 in list(countries.values()):
        try:
            countries_official[pycountry.countries.get(alpha_3 = alpha_3).official_name] = alpha_3
        except:
            None
    #same for common names
    for alpha_3 in list(countries.values()):
        try:
            countries_common[pycountry.countries.get(alpha_3 = alpha_3).common_name] = alpha_3
        except:
            None

    codes = []
    # appends ISO codes for all matches by trying different country name types
    # appends Unknown Country if no match found
    for i in input_countries:
        if i in countries.keys():
            codes.append(countries.get(i))

        elif i in countries_official.keys():
            codes.append(countries_official.get(i))

        elif i in countries_common.keys():
            codes.append(countries_common.get(i))

        else:
            codes.append('Unknown Country')
    return codes
```

Answer (score 0):

For simplistic sub-string matching, you can use `in`:

```
import pycountry

def get_country_code(name):
    for co in list(pycountry.countries):
        if name in co.name:
            return co.alpha_3
    return None

names = "Afghanistan", "Bolivia", "Iran", "Molvania", "I"

for name in names:
    print(name, get_country_code(name))
```

This produces:

```
Afghanistan AFG
Bolivia BOL
Iran IRN
Molvania None
I ALA
```

You'll need to decide how you want to handle search failures, in the above I return `None` which may not be useful. Also, only the first match is returned, so "I" matches the Aland **I**slands.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`clean_country()`](https://docs.dataprep.ai/user_guide/clean/clean_country.html) from the library [DataPrep](https://dataprep.ai/). Install it with `pip install dataprep`.

```py
from dataprep.clean import clean_country
df = pd.DataFrame({"Country": ["Afghanistan", "Bolivia", "Iran (Islamic Republic of)"]})
d2 = clean_country(df, "Country", output_format="alpha-3")
df2
                      Country Country_clean
0                 Afghanistan           AFG
1                     Bolivia           BOL
2  Iran (Islamic Republic of)           IRN
```